# How to get value in dictionary from 2 different string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have 2 string

```
string str="nl/vacature/admin/Employee/home/details/"
```

and other one

```
string template ="nl/vacature/{model}/{controller}/{Action}/{Method}/"
```

I am looking for

```
model=admin,controller=Employee,Action=home,Method=details
```

in an object or in dictionary in key-value format.Their URL and template key may be at different order it may be

`string template ="vacature/jobcount/{controller}/{Action}/{model}/{Method}/"`

```
string str ="vacature/jobcount/Employee/home/admin/details/"
```

Comment: Can you please be brief little, Could not understand anything, Please edit ASAP otherwise question will be downgraded and it will be deleted.

Comment: I have edited a few more point my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string url = "nl/vacature/admin/Employee/home/details/";
string template = "nl/vacature/{model}/{controller}/{Action}/{Method}/";

// remove unnecessary parts
template = template.Replace("nl/vacature/", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
url = url.Replace("nl/vacature/", "");

// dictionary, that will hold pairs, that you want
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

var urlList = url.Split('/');
var templateList = template.Split('/');

for(int i = 0; i < urlList.Length; i++) 
{
   dict.Add(templateList[i], urlList[i]);
}
```

I leave to you exception handling in case, that URLs won't consist of the same number of parts.

Comment: thank for replying me, I have edited a few more point my question

Comment: @ShivangGupta Answer is still valid

Comment: can we do this through Regex. which one is better Regex or the above one?

Comment: I would say above one, as regex is used to parse single strings (one string at a time), not multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Regex solution, but you need to change the template a little bit.

```
string url = "nl/vacature/admin/Employee/home/details/";
string template = "nl/vacature/(?<Model>.*?)/(?<Controller>.*?)/(?<Action>.*?)/(?<Method>.*?)/";
var matches = Regex.Match(url, template).Groups.Cast<Group>().Where(g => !int.TryParse(g.Name, out _)).ToDictionary(m => m.Name, m => m.Value);
// Dictionary<string, string>(4) { { "Model", "admin" }, { "Controller", "Employee" }, { "Action", "home" }, { "Method", "details" } }
```

However, external parsing library might be a better fit. You can find some URL parser instead of using regex.

Comment: thank for replying me, I have edited a few more point my question